# install maridb on debian jessie

Tags: installation, debian, mariadb

I wourld install mariaDB 10 on Debian 8 Jessie, but there occurred some errors at the installation.

```
[ ok ] Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.028-2+b1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.0 (>= 10.0.22-0+deb8u1); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.0
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

With The setup guide https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=host-europe, occurred the same errors for mariadb 10.1.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
after apt-get install mariadb*

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-5.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-5.2' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-5.3' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-5.5' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-oqgraph-engine-10.0' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-oqgraph-engine-10.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-cracklib-password-check-10.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-galera-server' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'libmariadbclient16' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'libmariadbclient18' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'libmariadb2' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-tokudb-engine-10.0' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test-5.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test-5.2' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test-5.3' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test-5.5' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-core-10.0' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-core-10.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'libmariadbclient-dev' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-core-10.0' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-core-10.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-core-5.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-core-5.2' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-core-5.3' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-core-5.5' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev-compat' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-galera-server-5.5' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-5.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-5.2' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-5.3' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-5.5' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-common' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-galera-server-10.0' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'libmariadbd-dev' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test-10.0' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test-10.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-10.0' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-10.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-10.0' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-10.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-core-5.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-core-5.2' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-core-5.3' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-core-5.5' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'libmariadbclient16-dev' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-connect-engine-10.0' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-tokudb-engine-5.5' for regex 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-connect-engine-10.1' for regex 'mariadb*'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev-compat : Conflicts: libmysqlclient-dev
 mariadb-client-10.0 : Conflicts: mysql-client-core-5.5
                       Conflicts: mysql-client-core-5.6
                       Breaks: mysql-client
                       Breaks: mysql-client-5.5
                       Breaks: mysql-client-5.6
                       Breaks: virtual-mysql-client
 mariadb-client-10.1 : Conflicts: mariadb-client-10.0 but 10.0.22-0+deb8u1 is to be installed
                       Conflicts: virtual-mysql-client
 mariadb-client-core-10.0 : Conflicts: mysql-client-5.5
                            Conflicts: mysql-client-5.6
                            Breaks: mysql-client-core-5.5
                            Breaks: mysql-client-core-5.6
                            Breaks: virtual-mysql-client-core
 mariadb-client-core-10.1 : Conflicts: mariadb-client-10.0 but 10.0.22-0+deb8u1 is to be installed
                            Conflicts: mariadb-client-core-10.0 but 10.0.22-0+deb8u1 is to be installed
                            Conflicts: virtual-mysql-client-core
 mariadb-server-10.0 : Conflicts: mysql-server-core-5.5
                       Conflicts: mysql-server-core-5.6
                       Breaks: mysql-client-5.5
                       Breaks: mysql-server
                       Breaks: virtual-mysql-server
 mariadb-server-10.1 : Conflicts: mariadb-server-10.0 but 10.0.22-0+deb8u1 is to be installed
                       Conflicts: virtual-mysql-server
 mariadb-server-core-10.0 : Breaks: mysql-client-5.5
                            Breaks: mysql-client-5.6
                            Breaks: mysql-server-core-5.5
                            Breaks: mysql-server-core-5.6
                            Breaks: virtual-mysql-server-core
 mariadb-server-core-10.1 : Conflicts: mariadb-server-core-10.0 but 10.0.22-0+deb8u1 is to be installed
                            Conflicts: virtual-mysql-server-core
 mariadb-test-10.0 : Breaks: virtual-mysql-testsuite
 mariadb-test-10.1 : Conflicts: mariadb-test-10.0 but 10.0.22-0+deb8u1 is to be installed
                     Conflicts: virtual-mysql-testsuite
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge mysql* mariadb*` and then `sudo apt-get install mariadb*`

Comment: thank you for your reply. The Error occurs again. I updated the question.

Comment: Can you give me remote ssh access to your machine??

Comment: I created a normal user for you, how I can send the login to you?

Comment: To my personal mail: robert.rozas.n@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have only 512 MB of RAM, and in order to install mariaDB, the process needs to allocate lot more memory:

```
Setting up mariadb-server-5.5 (5.5.47+maria-1~wheezy) ...
[ ok ] Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld.
160115 13:57:36 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.47-MariaDB-1~wheezy-log) starting as process 4208 ...
160115 13:57:36 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
160115 13:57:36 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 128917504 bytes)
160115 13:57:36 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 96681984 bytes)

160115 13:57:36 [ERROR] mysqld: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
160115 13:57:36 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
160115 13:57:36 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160115 13:57:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
ERROR: 1041  Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; 
if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space
```

You can add more memory to the VM or create a swap file. I delete every 
trace of mariadb on your machine, so, when you have the requirements filled
up, you can install it by just typing:

```
apt-get install mariadb-server
```